# GeoArea.STAsText() in sql server

Tags: sql-server, spatial

Is there any alternative of GeoArea.STAsText() in sql server?
I have the below query:

```
Select
    T.ClassType, 
    G.CorporationID, 
    G.ClassName,
    GeoArea.STAsText() As GeoText 
 From 
    Classtypes t 
    Inner Join Class g On T.PKClassTypeID = G.FKClassTypeID 
Where 
    T.ClassType In ('Shop','Home') And
    G.quarterid=10
```

This is taking very huge time to compute. But if I eliminate the `GeoArea.STAsText()` then my query runs in a fraction of seconds.
Is there a fast alternative to `GeoArea.STAsText()`?

Comment: It depends on what you want to use that data for. Do you need to pass it to another application? Do you want to examine it manually for some reason?

Comment: I need to pass the value to an application

Comment: Assuming that your application doesn't have access to the same database (which, if it does, you can pass the value by id), I'd try separate the identification of geo values and the deciding if then. That is, don't do the `STAsText()` in your query, output that result set into a temp table, and move the `STAsText()` into the select from the temp table